# How to change cell color in PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Are you able to change the color of a cell in a .xlsx file with PHPspreadsheet?  Couldn't find anything in their function list or on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Perhaps you should read the [docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/) particularly the section on styles

Comment: Thank you, I should have looked more carefully.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Tries to look this link
[Here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/)

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')
->getFont()->getColor()->setARGB(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED);
```

Comment: It is changing the Text color only. I want to change the Background of Cell

Comment: @IrshadKhan please check my answer above

Answer (score 8):

For those who understand "change cell color" as Background color and not Text color, the right code is:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('[YOUR_CELL_OR_RANGE_HERE]')->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('YOUR_COLOR_CODE_HERE');
```

Example:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E2')->getFill()
    ->setFillType(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Fill::FILL_SOLID)
    ->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFF0000');
```

Answer (score 0):

Tries to look this [link](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-rich-text-to-a-cell)

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getFont()->setColor(
    new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_RED)
);
```